# C++ data structure design: children with different fields and function

Tags: c++, oop

I just started learning C++ and I'm used to Java paradigms, so I'm not sure how this should be done:
I need to represent a vector of products of two different types: **packaged** and **fresh food**. They have some **common fields** with a single implementation (availability, re-stock quantity etc), but they have also **different fields and functions** with different return types.

> I.E: fresh foods may have a boolean field needsRefrigeration, other
>   products may have an integer representing a category (food, cleaning,
>   bricolage, forniture...).

In Java I would create a Product object with the common fields and a PackagedProduct (extending Product) plus a FreshProduct (also extending Product) with their particular fields. Then I'd place every product in a vector and accessed as Product when I need the common fields, safely-casted (with instanceof) to the right class when I need to access the child's fields.
I know this is not the right way in C++ and I don't want to force java programming paradigms to C++.

I can imagine:

- create all the functions required by all the cildren as virtual in the parent and add a field in the parent representing the type of the cild, so it can safely casted
- create a wrapper object containing two different vectors, each one of the type of a child object and return the values in the correct order, eventually using a third int vector.

I think these solutions are really bad, and I'm almost sure there must be a better way, but I can't imagine it. Can you help me?
What's the right way to do this?

Comment: `Then I'd place every product in a vector and accessed as Product when I need the common fields, safely-casted (with instanceof) to the right class when I need to access the child's fields. I know this is not the right way in C++` I strongly doubt `instanceof` and downcasting is the right way in Java, either.

Comment: Can you please split your brain dump into paragraphs?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to represent a vector of products of two different types: packaged and fresh food.

Do you really need both types of product in the same vector? Can't you have two vectors?

```
std::vector<PackagedProduct> packaged;
std::vector<FreshProduct> fresh;
packaged.emplace_back(1, 2, 3);
fresh.emplace_back(4, 5, 6);
```

This will be by far the most efficient solution. (Less indirections keep the prefetcher happy.)

If you absolutely need both kinds of products in the same vector, you must use indirection:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Product>> products;
products.push_back(std::make_unique<PackagedProduct>(1, 2, 3));
products.push_back(std::make_unique<FreshProduct>(4, 5, 6));
```

Instead of checking the dynamic type at runtime and downcast, you should read up on virtual methods.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is the same as in Java: Use inheritance to create a class hierarchy:

```
class Product { public: virtual ~Product(); ... };

class PackagedProduct : public Product { ... };
class FreshProduct : public Product { ... };
```

In Java, the vector (or list, container, ...) stores by-reference, not by-value. That's the crucial difference. In C++, this means using a smart pointer:

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Product > > v;

v.push_back( std::make_shared< FreshProduct >( some args... ) );
```

You can use `dynamic_pointer_cast` once you retrieved the pointer back from the vector to check what object it is, but other options are available.

This is, of course, just a rough idea and you'll need to learn a lot about the details, `shared_ptr`, etc. but I hope you have enough keywords and ideas to google now :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Product object with the common fields and a PackagedProduct (extending Product) plus a FreshProduct (also extending Product) with their particular fields.  Then store smart pointers to them in:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Product> > Vec;
```

Comment: `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`, no `std::` prefix, and the guy got this far already, he's saying that it's a bad design (he's right) and this does not contribute anything to that discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If FredOverflow's suggestion of using two vectors doesn't suit your needs, an alternative could be to make a variant of the two types and keep a vector of variants. This is fairly easy to do using [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html). You can wrap the functionality you need in free functions or you can wrap the variant in a class. Here's an example

```
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp>

struct FreshProduct
{
  double price;
  bool needsRefrigeration;
};

struct PackagedProduct
{
  double price;
};

struct VariantProduct
{
  VariantProduct(const FreshProduct& p) : product(p) {}
  VariantProduct(const PackagedProduct& p) : product(p) {}

  double getPrice() const;
  bool needsRefrigeration() const
  {
    struct helper : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
    {
      bool operator ()(const FreshProduct& product) const
      {
        return product.needsRefrigeration;
      }
      bool operator ()(...) const
      {
        return false;
      }
    };
    return boost::apply_visitor(helper(), product);
  }

private:
  boost::variant<FreshProduct, PackagedProduct> product;
};

// in cpp

namespace {
  struct GetPrice : public boost::static_visitor<double>
  {
    template <class T>
    double operator ()(const T& product) const
    {
      return product.price;
    }
  };
} // anonymous namespace

double VariantProduct::getPrice() const
{
  return boost::apply_visitor(GetPrice(), product);
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to use dynamic allocation in order to keep a collection of fresh or packaged products. The downside is that it is not so easy to extend the types supported in the variant as when using inheritance.